# Puppet - Ensure cent base repo is present

Tags: puppet, repository, rpm

Using a puppet manifest, how do you ensure the official cent 'base' repo is present.

Example to add an internal cent repo

http://seriousbirder.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-puppet-yum-repo-module/

Example for debian systems

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, you'll see the entries map cleanly to the examples in the link you provided: http://seriousbirder.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-puppet-yum-repo-module/

For instance:

```
      yumrepo {
     "CentOS6-Base":
        descr          => "CentOS-\$releasever - Base",
        mirrorlist     => "http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os",
        gpgcheck       => "1",
        gpgkey         => "file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6",
        enabled        => "1";
      } ### End yumrepo::
```